# NextJS custom server gives CORS error after build with 'npm run build'

Tags: node.js, build, axios, cors, next.js

This was working fine.  I was using **npm run dev** to start this custom server (*server.js* code below). I needed to have production build with *Server Side Rendering* and couldn't use **next export**.

After I run **npm run build**, the authentication wasn't working. I found the backend server was not receiving cookies. So I added, `withCredentials: true` in axios request. But then all request are getting blocked by **cors policy**. The error message is,

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:5002/api/v1/users/authenticate’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

I am using *cors* package in my *backend nodejs express server*.

I tried every internet solution. Allowing cors origin on client and server, using cors options to have localhost as origin. But none works.

Here is the nextjs custom server code,

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const apiPaths = {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:5002',
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': '/api',
    },
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
};

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    if (isDevelopment) {
      server.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware(apiPaths['/api']));
    }

    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error:::::', err);
  });
```

The client code with Axios,

```
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {

          const data = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/v1/users/authenticate`,

            withCredentials: true,
            data: { token },
          });
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you configure CORS in your backend?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh
//enable proxy
app.enable('trust-proxy');

//cors

app.use('/api/', cors());
app.options('*', cors());

Here is my backend cors.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error

> The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
> ‘http://localhost:5002/api/v1/users/authenticate’. (Reason: Credential
> is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is
> ‘*’).

What it said is: when you include the credential in the request `withCredentials: true,`, the origin cannot be "*", which is the default option when using `cors())`. You can specify the origin of the request in the cors options. You also need to add the "credentials" option to pass the header.

```
const corsOptions = {
       origin : "YOUR_FRONTEND", // the origin of the requests - frontend address
       credentials : true  
}
```

Then :

```
app.use('/api/', cors(corsOptions)); 
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the cors library to your Express API. It allows you to run cors requests from your API.

Install cors and then add the middleware by using

```js
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors())
```

Your CORS rules can be customized ofc. With the code above you essentially allow all CORS requests from any origin.

Comment: Already using cors. But I found the problem, I was using backend api link http://localhost:5002/api/v1 from process.env. It works when I just use relative url in axios. But now, how to proxy the next production build to backend like the development server?